# How to make a list of strings into a dictionary where all the words in the string are keys and the first item in each string is the value of those key

Tags: python, string, dictionary

So I'm trying to get a dictionary from a list of strings
the list looks something like this

```
['4 it was amazing', '0 it was awful', '3 it was ok']
```

i want the dictionary to look like

```
{'it': 7, 'was': 7, 'amazing': 4, 'awful': 0, 'ok':3}
```

where each item of the dictionary gets the number the string begins with and if the key has already shown up it will add to the old value.

```
total_dic = {}
    for string in list:
        words = string.split()
        total_dic[words[1]] = words[0]
        total_dic[words[2]] = words[0]
        total_dic[words[3]] = words[0]

    return total_dic
```

this replaces the values for duplicate keys i want to add the value, also if the string is bigger than 3 words i don't know how to make sure it keeps going

Comment: "this replaces the values for duplicate keys i want to add the value" ok, did you try *adding the value*?

Comment: Your code appears to be storing numeric strings as values e.g. `'it': '4'`, when you need actual numbers e.g. `'it': 4`. See [How to Convert a Python String to int](https://realpython.com/convert-python-string-to-int/).

Comment: Don't use `list` as name. It's already a Python built-in.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be:

```py
def word_count(lst):
    word_dict = {}

    for string in lst:
        words = string.split(' ')

        for word in words[1:]:
            if word in word_dict.keys():
                word_dict[word] += int(words[0])
            else:
                word_dict[word] = int(words[0])

    return word_dict
```

Here, I added a check if the key already exists in `word_dict`. If it does, I add to it. In addition, I made sure that the values stored in the `word_dict` are integers.

There is a cleaner solution:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def word_count(lst):
    word_dict = defaultdict(int)

    for string in lst:
        count, *words = string.split()
        for word in words:
            word_dict[word] += int(count)

    return word_dict
```

In this version, I use the `defaultdict(int)` constructor to create a dictionary where the default value of a missing key is `0`. Then, I iterate over the input list and use extended iterable unpacking (`*words`) to split each string into a count and a list of words. Finally, I update the count for each word in the dictionary using `word_dict[word] += int(count)`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Was going to add the defaultdic to my answer, but yours came first :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a comprehension in an update on the resulting dictionary:

```
strings = ['4 it was amazing', '0 it was awful', '3 it was ok']

counts = dict()
counts.update( (word, counts.get(word,0)+int(n)) 
               for n,*words in map(str.split,strings)
               for word in words )

print(counts)
{'it': 7, 'was': 7, 'amazing': 4, 'awful': 0, 'ok': 3}
```